# POST method not working using node js and express with mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, express

GET method works with me just fine

i have a database named stage4 and im trying to insert values to it from the a frontend page

and it is connected , i'm using postman to test it first
but it return "404 error"
an error i've set

```
    const q = "INSERT INTO stage4.TOURIST ('Fname', 'Lname', 'Tourist_ID', 'age', 'gender', 'email', 'nationality' VALUES (?)";
    const values = ["first name", "last name", "tourist id",
        "age", "gender", "email", "nationality"];
    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.json("404 error")
        return res.json("works")
    })
})
```

any idea that might help me with it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1- First make sure the request Type in POST man of that specific request is POST

2- And try this piece of code

```
var sql = `INSERT INTO TOURIST 
            (
                Fname, Lname, Tourist_ID, age, gender, email, nationality
            )
            VALUES
            (
                ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
            )`;
connection.query(sql, [Fname, Lname, Tourist_ID, age, gender, email, nationality], function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // some error occured
    } else {
        // successfully inserted into db
    }
});
```

3- Database name must be mention in the connection string and not the insert statement

```
const config = {
  db: {
    host: "db4free.net",//example
    user: "restapitest123",//example
    password: "restapitest123",//example
    database: "restapitest123",//example
  },
  listPerPage: 10,
};
```